# Destructuring assignment in for...of loop and execution context in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring, executioncontext

I want to get deep understanding of the for...of loops and destructuring assignment in JS. The following code throw an error on line 3: "ReferenceError: y is not defined", but "y" is defined just before the for loop statement. What's the problem?

```
let arr = [ ];
let y = 8;
for (let { x = 2, y } of [{ x: 1 }, 2, { y }]) {  
    arr.push(x, y);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `y` is in a [temporal dead zone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_dead_zone) in the `for` block.

Not using `y` in the object initialisation solves the problem:

```js
let arr = [];
let z = 8;
for (let { x = 2, y } of [{ x: 1 }, 2, { y: z }]) {  
  arr.push(x, y);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This is weird. It's [an environment explicitly created for evaluating only this expression](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-runtime-semantics-forin-div-ofheadevaluation-tdznames-expr-iterationkind), what would it be used for?

Comment: It seems that they separate the head from the body, and each has a TDZ of each own.